# openmp on dev c++

Tags: openmp

Is there anyway to use openmp with dev c++. I have seen links on how to use in Visual Studio, but i am more comfortable with Dev C++ interface.
Adding /openmp in the linker command line doesnt work either. 
I couldnt find the library to download too. Am i missing something.
I tried running this sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    { 
       printf("Hello, world.\n");
    }
   return 0;
 }
```

From where I read it was mentioned Output on a computer with 2 Cores and 2 threads will be hello world printed twice. I have a core i7 but it was printed only once.

Comment: Where do you create a second thread? And FYI those headers are deprecated in C++.

Comment: @Tomalak The second thread is created by OpenMP, and the headers are just fine if this is C (but yeah, the question suggests that it’s C++).

Comment: Dev-C++ is outdated. Its development has stopped half a decade ago. Please use a modern IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know Dev C++, but to enable openmp you also need to add the flag -fopenmp to your compiler.
 Additional to linking to omp.

With g++ it look like this

g++ yourProgram.cpp -o yourProgram -lgomp -fopenmp

`-fopenmp` will tell the compiler to generate parallel code. I hope this will help.

Comment: Dev-C++ is an IDE. It invokes `g++` by default (albeit the MinGW port).

Answer (score 10):

Tools > Compiler Options > Check the option "Add the following commands when compiler is called" > in the text area put "-fopenmp"

Compile and execute again :)

Comment: This helps. I think this is the answer that should be selected as the right one since the other one doesn't tell you how to do this on Dev C++.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include `-fopenmp` in

1. Project-> Project Option->Parameters - Link
   and
2. Tools ->Compiler Options (General)
   (check "add the following commands when calling the compiler"
   and include `-fopenmp` in the textBox

I have also included `#include <omp.h>`
dev-c++ version 5.6.1

Answer (score 0):

there is only the parallel region , the processor is informed that there is what parallelize , but as is parallelize the code they have to say via builders, probably what you want to use : #pragma omp sections

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also have to include the header file **#include < omp.h >** separately